# Azure AD Service Principle Authentication for AWS

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, amazon-iam

I have code running in an Azure Web App with a managed service identity (which is basically a client_id and client_secret for a registered Azure AD Application).

I have an Enterprise Application registered in Azure AD and a corresponding Identity Provider registered in AWS IAM. Interactive federated SSO for users from Azure AD through to AWS works fine.

But I want my Web App to use its client credentials to perform a non-interactive SSO to either end up with an OAuth2 token or SAML assertion that can then be used for API calls to AWS.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use: [Azure Active Directory v2.0 and the OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds)

Comment: ...how? I can get a token for the enterprise application from Azure AD but how will I get one that is usable in AWS?